# Cannot access scope variable set using Mongoose query within controller

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

In my MEANJS app. I am setting the value of a scope variable to a query result, from my controller function

```
$scope.myVar = User.query();
console.dir($scope.myVar);     //Returns all the documents from the DB correctly
console.log('User's name is : ' + $scope.myVar[0].name);   //This comes as undefined
```

Somehow, in the very next line when I am trying to open the name field within the same controller function, it comes as undefined. Also, the entire result is being read absolutely correctly in my view file. So when I call

```
{{myVar.name}}
```

within my view file it outputs the name correctly. I cannot understand this behavior at all. This is my first time working with Angularjs, and I could have missed something basic, but I appreciate any help at this point.

Edit - Also the length of $scope.myVar is always 0 within the controller

Comment: This is browser console magic. :) When you expand the object from the console.dir, the console re-requests data from the var, thus showing the populated document. The console.log on the other hand generates the string based on the contents of myVar at that point in time and doesn't update it when the object is available.

Comment: Wow, thank you for that nugget, there was no way in hell I would have figured that one out. But my problem persists, coz I need to perform some operations on $scope.myVar once it has the result of the query. For which I need to run through it using $scope.myVar.length. But in this case, length is always 0. No browser involved here, but I am still not able to access $scope.myVar within the controller.

Comment: You need to use the done or success callback of the query you are sending so that the code won't run until there is data for it to interact with.

Comment: does your `User.query()` returns promise?

Comment: @KevinB - Thanks, going to go try that

Comment: @pankajparkar - Yes it returns a promise object, but I am not entirely sure what to do with it, still new to angularjs unfortunately

Comment: @monologish please do check my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Found the answer. The callback functions in meanjs are in this format:

```
 var myObj= User.query(function(response) {
                console.log('Inside success response');
                 //Can access myObj values here easily
            }, function(errResponse) {
                console.log('Inside error response ' + errResponse);
        });
```

I wasn't able to figure out how to access my $scope.myVar within the controller, but I completed a workaround by creating my own factory method to retrieve data the way I wanted it sorted. The problem of not being able to access these query results is really posing a problem in other parts as well. So if anyone has an answer, please do let me know.

For now posting the link I used to figure out how the MEAN.JS factory method needs to be plugged in. Hope this helps someone.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/meanjs/query()/meanjs/4R7rIolH9bs/P1R4YlKgowUJ

Answer (score 0):

Basically `User.query()` returns a promise object, so you need to update you `$scope` object inside promise success.

**Code**

```
User.query().$promise.then(function(res){
   //you will get response here in data obj
   $scope.myVar = res;
   console.dir($scope.myVar);//Returns all the documents from the DB correctly
   console.log('User's name is : ' + $scope.myVar[0].name);   //This comes as undefined
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's giving an error, stating undefined is not a function on the line I added .then(function...) to. I just found this solution on the MEAN.JS Google group that explains that the User.query() is a factory call, which then calls the server function. So I cannot add any other functions to this. Still does not explain why I cannot read the value of myVar in my controller though, going to try a work around :/. Thanks.

Comment: @monologish could you please tell me what is `.query()` is it custom factory / `$http` call / `$resource` call

Comment: @monologish  then it should be using `User.query().$promise.then`

Comment: Ok so that removed the error, but it also removed the results. Now $scope.myVar is undefined. Sorry if I am making this hard to figure out, I am still new to Angularjs

Comment: @monologish its ok dude, I'm here to help..could you please change your line to `$scope.myVar = res;`

Comment: changing it to res worked halfway. I have my results back, but the problem is still the same. I cannot access myVar within the controller function, even right after the $promise.then function. I read somewhere that you are supposed to put your business logic within services and not in controllers, could that be a reason why I'm not getting access to $scope.myVar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74963/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-monologish).